# How to do random node scan in NebulaGraph database?

Tags: nebula-graph, opencypher

I tried to fetch 10 random and non-isolated nodes in the Nebula Graph database. According to their docs the query should be `MATCH (n:tag)-[e]-() RETURN n LIMIT 10`. But it fails to work.

The screenshots of running the query is as follows:
[image]

What is wrong with my query? Such a simple query should not be wrong.

Comment: The NebulaGraph database version is 3.1.2. The NebulaGraph Explorer version is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no index has been created. If you want to execute `MATCH (n:tag)-[e]-() RETURN n LIMIT 10`, please create at least one [index](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/14.native-index-statements/1.create-native-index/).

If you don't want to create indexes here, you must specify the direction of the edge. For example `MATCH (n:tag)-[e]->() RETURN n LIMIT 10`

Comment: Thank you foesa. But I actually set the direction of the edge. Please see my screenshot. I ran `MATCH (n:Person)-[e]-() RETURN n LIMIT 10` but still got the same error.

Comment: And yes, I don't want to create an index for such a test. Indexes can be disk-consuming.